# how to create custom endpoints and multiple connection in jsplumb

Tags: jsplumb

Can we create custom endpoints in jsplumb, apart from usual dot, rectangle etc i want to use rectangle outside my div as shown below

[image]

also how can i use this for multiple connections as show below.

[image]

example code will help me more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it in the JsPlumb library directly.

The way I solved this issue was to draw html or svg over the actual jsPlumb endpoint.

There is a caveat in doing it this way though. You can not have dynamic endpoints you can only use the fixed endpoints. I think you could setup some javascript that matches the location of the endpoint. But that just seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining the endpoint, check if you're setting the **maxConnections** parameter.

For example, when you set maxConnections : -1, it will enable the endpoint to accept infinite number of connections